# Add borders around individual bar graph plots based on a column: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph using the following dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(country.name = structure(c(4L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 
       3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Czech Republic", 
       "Denmark", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", 
       "Sweden", "Switzerland"), class = "factor"), level = c(2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), no.regions = c(5L, 7L, 8L, 
       11L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 14L), min_result = c(42.59, 33.57, 
       43.1, 38.46, 41.76, 44.05, 41.67, 36.32, 36.18, 42.79, 39.91), 
       max_result = c(50.24, 46.56, 58.24, 57.41, 61.07, 64.56, 
       63.25, 58.19, 59.14, 69.19, 67.11), diff = c(7.65, 12.99, 
       15.14, 18.95, 19.31, 20.51, 21.58, 21.87, 22.96, 26.4, 27.2
       ), RD = c(-0.07, 0.131, -0.091, -0.153, -0.172, 0.203, -0.166, 
       0.145, -0.228, -0.266, -0.261), RDCI_lower = c(-0.21, -0.028, -0.194, -0.328, -0.376, 0.076, -0.315, 0.075, -0.407, -0.348, 
       -0.347), RDCI_upper = c(0.07, 0.29, 0.012, 0.021, 0.031, 
      0.331, -0.017, 0.216, -0.049, -0.184, -0.175), RDpvalue = c(0.3237, 
      0.1113, 0.08, 0.0829, 0.1017, 0.0023, 0.0299, 0, 0.0149, 
      0, 0), diff_order = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Denmark", 
       "Switzerland", "Sweden", "Belgium", "Austria", "Czech Republic", 
      "Norway", "France", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Germany"), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(19.31, 
      18.95, 20.51, 7.65, 21.87, 27.2, 22.96, 21.58, 26.4, 15.14, 
      12.99), .Dim = 11L, .Dimnames = list(c("Austria", "Belgium", 
      "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", 
      "Norway", "Poland", "Sweden", "Switzerland"))))), .Names = c("country.name", 
      "level", "no.regions", "min_result", "max_result", "diff", "RD", 
      "RDCI_lower", "RDCI_upper", "RDpvalue", "diff_order"), row.names = c(NA, 
      -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

My initial graph is:

```
a <- ggplot(df1, aes((x=diff_order), y=diff,fill=as.factor(level))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("Country") +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2B2B2B", "#555555"),name="NUTS level") +
  ggtitle("All")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="bold"))

a
```

Now, I want to add borders round my bar graph plots depending on whether the RDpvalue is < 0.05 (to visually show significance).

Is it possible to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `color` aesthetic:

```
df1$color_grp <- ifelse(df1$RDpvalue < 0.05,'Yes','No')

a <- ggplot(df1, 
            aes(x=diff_order, 
                y=diff,
                fill=as.factor(level),
                color = color_grp)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    xlab("Country") +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2B2B2B", "#555555"),name="NUTS level") +
    ggtitle("All")  +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9),
          axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="bold"))

a
```

Comment: Great - @joran.  But how can I remove this legend (not the one related to fill) from my graph?  I have tried + guides(color = FALSE) ...but I get the error Error in ggtitle("All") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator  What has gone wrong?

Comment: @KT_1 Adding `guides(color = FALSE)` worked fine for me. You have some syntax error somewhere else. Note that I edited the code in your original question because it contained a syntax error that I presumed was a typo.

Comment: Actually, @joran.  When I try and add my own colurs (e.g. scale_color_manual(values=c("white", "black")) - and then try to remove the legend, this is when I get the error.  Why might that be?

Comment: @KT_1 No idea. `a +scale_color_manual(values = c("red","black")) + guides(color = FALSE)` works just fine for me.